# Crear arbol de directorios (lista) a partir de rutas - PHP

Tags: php, rutas

Tengo que entregar un proyecto mañana y se me ha ocurrido una cosa de última hora, tras hacer una consulta a MySQL me llegan varias rutas:

```
/Fotos

/Fotos/Viajes

/Fotos/Viajes/Madrid

/Fotos/Viajes/Barcelona
```

Cada ruta es una fila en la base de datos, por cada registro hago un `explode()` y lo convierto en un array, pero ahí me bloqueo y no se como continuar.

Teniendo estos datos llegados de registros diferentes de MySQL, necesitaria generar una lista con subniveles para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
<li>Fotos
  <ul>
    <li>Viajes
      <ul>
        <li>Madrid</li>
        <li>Barcelona</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Gracias a todos

Comment: podrias indicar como tienes la estructura de tu tabla de donde extraes la info

Comment: La ruta total es.




**[PADRE]**: floud/email/ **[NOMBRE]**: Fotos/  

**[PADRE]**: floud/email/Fotos/ **[NOMBRE]**: Viajes/ 

**[PADRE]**: floud/email/Fotos/Viajes/ **[NOMBRE]**: Madrid/ 

**[PADRE]**: floud/email/Fotos/Viajes/ **[NOMBRE]**: Barcelona/

Comment: Perdon, no se hacer saltos de linea. Utilizo explode() para eliminar floud/email de todas las rutas

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo PHP y lo que has intentado

Comment: while($stmt->fetch()){
  $cadena = explode("/", $padre);
  $rutaarchivo = "";
  for ($i=2; $i < count($cadena); $i++) { 

   $rutaarchivo = $rutaarchivo."/".$cadena[$i]; 

  }
  echo $rutaarchivo.substr($nombre, 0, -1)."<br>";
 }